# Meteor.js with drop zone

Tags: javascript, meteor, dropzone.js

So I'm using https://github.com/devonbarrett/meteor-dropzone to add a dropzone upload section to a meteor application. So I have my template:

```
<template name = "upload">
    {{> dropzone url='/upload'  id='dropzoneDiv' maxFiles=2}}
</template>
```

and I designate a route using the iron router for receiving the files:

```
Router.map(function(){
    this.route = ('upload');

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var dropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneDiv", {

        accept: function(file, done){
            console.log("true");

        }
    });
});
```

But I keep getting an error message saying "Error: invalid dropzone element". I also tried creating the drop zone instance using jQuery ready function,  but this didn't work either. Does anyone know why I'm receiving this error?

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking your `upload` route with your drop zone's setup: you do not have to call `new Dropzone()` anywhere in your code, [that is what the `meteor-dropzone` package does for you](https://github.com/devonbarrett/meteor-dropzone/blob/master/lib/dbarrett:dropzonejs.js) within its `dropzone` template that you called.

In your `upload` route, you should not have any mention of Dropzone whatsoever: it is the route that will receive the data sent from your dropzone element. Instead you should put in your upload route some upload and storage logic:

```
Router.route('/upload',{
  name:'uploadRoute'
})
.post(function () {
    var body = this.request.body; // your file is in there. Do what you want with it.
});
```

Also, you should probably use a helper to get the full url to your route:

```
Template.upload.helpers({
  getUploadUrl: function () {
    return Router.routes.uploadRoute.url();
  }
});
```

And change your template to:

```
<template name="upload">
  {{> dropzone url=getUploadUrl id='dropzoneDiv' maxFiles=2}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm going to try this.

Comment: For some reason, once I upload a file, it never goes to the url 'upload'

Comment: Dropzone probably dislikes your "/upload" url. Try using `{{> dropzone url=getUploadUrl  id='dropzoneDiv' maxFiles=2}}` instead, with `getUploadUrl` being a template helper that returns `Router.routes.upload.url()`